# Attach CustomComponent to html Element (paper-drawer-panel)

Tags: java, html, polymer, vaadin

I'm using the Elements add-on from the Vaadin Labs to build my web app.  I'm currently trying to use a paper-drawer-panel from polymer to provide navigation, but I can't see how to add Vaadin layouts or components to an Element.  Any ideas on how to set the Vaadin layout/component to 'main' for paper-drawer-panel?

Comment: Can you link the Elements addon?

Comment: https://vaadin.com/labs-elements